# Iptrack Magento

Tags: magento, ip

I use Iptrack extension in Magento. Based on IP detection the following specifications will be shown for a product (if applicable);
Specifications - it is attribute for product.

if IP is from the UK or US and language is English :
Show all I- and G-specifications

other IP's and languages :
Show all M- and G-specifications

This is where attributes come: `attributes.phtml`:

```
<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $_product = $this->getProduct()
?>
<?php if($_additional = $this->getAdditionalData()): ?>
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Additional Information') ?></h2>
    <table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
        <col width="25%" />
        <col />
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
            <tr>
                <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('product-attribute-specs-table')</script>
<?php endif;?>
```

dumping `$_data` inside `foreach` give me like

```
array(3) { ["label"]=> string(19) "Diameter D (inches)" ["value"]=> string(7) "2 11/16" ["code"]=> string(4) "i062" } Diameter D (inches)
```

for one loop.

Maybe someone got the same problem? Thank you.

Comment: You need to be way more specific. Never heard of I-/G-/M-specifications (probably too localized).

Comment: I-/G-/M-specifications - it's my attributes for products. For example m003 - Attribute Code. Where m - it's specification.

Comment: If it's an attribute then a `$collection->addAttributeToFilter()` usually is all you need. Please post your code building the product collection to be shown.

Comment: hope i posted right page ;)

Comment: Ok, so we are not talking about collections, but a single product. You only told us `m003` is one of your custom product attribute names. Please list all the I/G/M attribute names too, so we can see what naming logic you use.

Comment: Also we using `i001`, `i002`(attr code) and etc - fo I specification, `g001`, `g002`..for G spec. All specifications have about 200 same names, but for diffrent countries - example - `i228`  Length A (**inches**)  
`m228`  Length A (**mm**). So we use both now for all IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can achieve what you want by something like this:

```
<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $_product = $this->getProduct();
    function isAllowedAttribute($aData)
    {
        $bIpCheck = (bool) preg_match('/^[igm]{1}[0-9]{3}$/', $aData['code']);
        if (!$bIpCheck) {
            return true;
        }
        if (isIpFromUkOrUsAndLanguageEnglish()) {
            return (bool) preg_match('/^[ig]{1}[0-9]{3}$/', $aData['code']);            
        }
        else {
            return (bool) preg_match('/^[mg]{1}[0-9]{3}$/', $aData['code']);            
        }
    }
?>
<?php if($_additional = $this->getAdditionalData()): ?>
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Additional Information') ?></h2>
    <table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
        <col width="25%" />
        <col />
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
            <?php if (isAllowedAttribute($_data)): ?>
                <tr>
                    <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                    <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('product-attribute-specs-table')</script>
<?php endif;?>
```

I don't know this IP track extension you use at all, so I simply used a dummy call to a non-existing function named `isIpFromUkOrUsAndLanguageEnglish()`.

You only need to replace this by the proper IP track extension call(s).

Comment: if i replace my code to this, it's not working :( even only function.

Comment: Is the `attributes.phtml` you posted proven to be used? Or is this the wrong template?

Comment: If the `attributes.phtml` is proven to be used, please add a dump of `$_data` to your post.

Comment: i made dump and edit post. I check, i use exactly `attributes.phtml`

Comment: Then this should work for sure. Please replace `isIpFromUkOrUsAndLanguageEnglish()` against `1==1` to force the `if` case to be triggered. According to your added dump `code => 'i061'` the output should contain a `Diameter D (inches)` label then.

Comment: also need to check `if (! function_exists('isAllowedAttribute')) { function inside }` thank you so much!